# Mysql Syntax Error

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am receiving the following error and cannot find the problem:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''String', 'String', '6', 'String', 'String', 'String', 'The' at line 1

C# code:

```
    protected void updateDB(byte[] content, int size, string mime)
{
    string school = DropDownList_School.Text;
    string subject = DropDownList_Subject.Text;
    string teacher = DropDownList_Teacher.Text;
    string course = DropDownList_Class.Text;
    string unit = TextBox_Unit.Text;
    string name = TextBox_Name.Text;
    string date = DateTime.Today.ToString();
    string username = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().UserName;
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnection"].ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();//(query, connection);
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO uploads 
                       (@School, @Subject, @Teacher, @Course, @Unit, @Name, @Username, @Size, @MIME, @content) ";
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@School", school);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", subject);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher", teacher);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", course);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit", unit);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", size);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MIME", mime);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", content);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

The ConnectionString is correct.

Comment: try INSERT INTO upload (field1, field2) VALUES (@value1, @value2)

Comment: @Fernando Costa : the fields & VALUES isn't necessary if inserting values into all fields in the table -- the OPs query is valid

Comment: @OMG Ponies, good practice to use them because if they are of the same type then sql could guess which column incorrectly (especially if you put them in the wrong order accidentally and the types are valid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be `INSERT INTO uploads VALUES(...)`
You might also want to specify the column order such as `INSERT INTO uploads(col1, col2, etc...) VALUES(val for col1, val for col2..., etc)` because if not then SQL will try to "guess" and it can guess wrong.

Comment: Thanks! yeah I have to go with the second one. Converting to prepared statements and missed a step.

Comment: was my answer, is that wrong?!? 
try INSERT INTO upload (field1, field2) VALUES (@value1, @value2) ...   0_o

Comment: its columns not fields, also I answered it first

Comment: well fernando answered first i think... but it wasnt an answer... it was a comment. no way to accept that right?

Comment: nope and if you check the times I did answer first, I edited to fix a formatting error i had with a code tag